# Send Web Push Notification to FIREFOX browser using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can any one please help me, how to send web push notifications to firefox browser (Desktop and mobile)?

For sending push notification to chrome browser, i am using the following steps.
1) Create application in FCM( to get sender id and api key)
2) Getting endpoints (registration ids) using javascript method shown in google docs.
3) Sending push notification to all registrations ids using asp.net c#.
Below is the code

```
protected void SubmitButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  AndroidPush(); // calling android push method
}

//Android push message to GCM server method
private void AndroidPush() 
{
  // your RegistrationID paste here which is received from GCM server.
  string regId = "APA91bG_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_V6hO2liMx-
  eIGAbG2cR4DiIgm5Q ";
    // applicationID means google Api key
  var applicationID = "AIzaSyDScBxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxpv66IfgA";
  // SENDER_ID is nothing but your ProjectID (from API Console- google code)//
  var SENDER_ID = "77xxxxx625";
  var value = Text1.Text; //message text box                                                                        
  WebRequest tRequest;
  tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
  tRequest.Method = "post";
  tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
  tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));
  tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));
  //Data post to server                                                                                                         
  string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + regId + "";
  Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
  tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
  Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
  dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
  dataStream.Close();
  WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();
  dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();
  StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
  String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd(); //Get response from GCM server.
  Label3.Text = sResponseFromServer; //Assigning GCM response to Label text 
  tReader.Close();
  dataStream.Close();
  tResponse.Close();
}
```

Comment: Have you got any solution?